# iOS: NSNotification unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"locationObtained" object:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotification:notification];
```

I get `[LocavoreRetroFirstViewController startServices]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74c3070`

```
- (void)listenForLocationCompletion{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(startServices)
                                                name:@"locationObtained"
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)startServices:(NSNotification *)notification{

}
```

Any reason why I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(startServices:)
                                                name:@"locationObtained"
                                              object:nil];
}
```

**Your selector startServices missed a ":" at end**

Answer (score 1):

You have a `LocavoreRetroFirstViewController` object that registered for the `locationObtained` notification and has since be deallocated.

Add this in LocavoreRetroFirstViewController's implementation file:

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether you have a method called `startServices`? Is `LocavoreRetroFirstViewController`'s object alive after posting the notification? Please post notification's observer code so that I can get more idea.

Comment: Yes I have: - (void)listenForLocationCompletion{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(startServices)
                                                name:@"locationObtained"
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)startServices:(NSNotification *)notification{

}

Comment: Come on you have missed a ':' there it should be @selector(startServices:) and not @selector(startServices). Try now!!

Comment: @EliMiller: now start upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon in the selector name.

It should be `@selector(startServices:)`.

Comment: Yup forgot ":" for selector

Comment: I did the same mistake many times ;) I'm glad you solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you